# hour backup of Azure file share with PowerShell command

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-storage-account, azure-runbook

I want to backup azure file every hour but since backup policy only allow us to do so every 4 hours as minimum, I want to trigger an on-demand backup hourly with PowerShell command. I tried to use Runbook in Azure automation in the below code, but I got an error indicated in the below(I also tried with Connect-AzAccount using my login name and password, but it does not work).

Any suggestion?

---

**Code:**

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName ServicePrincipalName

$SecureStringPwd = $sp.PasswordCredentials.SecretText | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $sp.AppId, $SecureStringPwd
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId


Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name "vault641" | Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext

$afsContainer=Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -FriendlyName "testtest" -ContainerType AzureStorage

$afsBkpItem=Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $afsContainer -FriendlyName "test" -WorkloadType "AzureFiles"
$job = Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $afsBkpItem
```

**Error:**

```
New-AzADApplication_CreateExpanded: C:\ModulesV2\Global\Az.Resources\MSGraph.Autorest\custom\New-AzADApplication.ps1:689
Line |
 689 |      $app = Az.MSGraph.internal\New-AzADApplication @PSBoundParameters
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The context is invalid. Please login using Connect-AzAccount.
New-AzADApplication: C:\ModulesV2\Global\Az.Resources\MSGraph.Autorest\custom\New-AzADServicePrincipal.ps1:732
Line |
 732 |        $app = New-AzADApplication @param
     |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is an empty
     | string.
```

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/manage-afs-backup#create-a-new-policy?

Comment: Thanks @Rukmini. But Backup policy only allow every 4 hours(6, 8 and 12 hours only) as minimum, though it says "hourly".... So in order to do the backup every hour, I think I need to run on demand backup. And we cannot run manually every hour, so we would like to run in the automation.

Answer (score 0):

I added 4 lines below after "create PowerShell runbook" in [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity#create-powershell-runbook.). I also needed to add "Az.Accounts", "Az.ManagedServiceIdentity" and "Az.RecoveryServices" in "Modules" under "Shared Resources" of "Automation Accounts" in Azure portal. Then it works.

```
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "my-resource-group-name" -Name "my-recover-service-vault-name"
$Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureStorage -FriendlyName "my-storage-name" -VaultId $vault.ID
$BackupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $Container -WorkloadType AzureFiles -VaultId $vault.ID -FriendlyName "my-File-share-name"
$job = Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $BackupItem -VaultId $vault.ID
```